# Delete only those folders and files that are not used by another resources from windows 'Temp 'folder using Gradle task

Tags: gradle, groovy, build, build.gradle

I am writing a gradle script to delete files and folder which are not used by other resources inside the 'Temp' folder in Windows i.e `%TEMP%'`. However, if some files are used by another resources, then it will not delete and throw exception when I try to delete. I tried:

```
task cleanTempFile(type: Delete) {
    def directoryPath = "/path/to/temp/folder.."
    file(directoryPath).deleteDir();
}
```

This will actually work as expected (not delete used ones but delete the ones that are not used by any resources). However, the problem is that it deletes the 'Temp' folder itself. I want to KEEP the Temp folder but delete contents inside of it. I tried :

```
task cleanTempFile(type: Delete) {
     //delete files
     delete fileTree(dir: 'path/to/temp/folder' , include: '**/*.*')
      //deletes folder
      file( directoryPath ).list().each{
        a -> delete "path/to/temp/folder/${a}"
    }
}
```

but it gives me error saying unable to delete the file. It does not work if any of the files and folder are used by other resources (e.g open a file and try to delete the folder, unopened or unused are not deleted). Is there any way I can achieve this? I appreciate any help or suggestion. Thank you.